# How to draw a graph in PHP?

Tags: php, draw

Hey I want to draw a graph(Stdent mark distribution) in my site based on PHP. How can I do this?

Answer (score 24):

[pChart](http://www.pchart.net/) is another great PHP graphing library.

Comment: pChart worked for me, it's a resource rich library and very powerful!!! Thanx John

Comment: Hiccup: It's GPL. No mention of LGPL.

Comment: GPL is fine for server-side stuff.

Comment: GPL is not fine for server-side stuff if you are re-distributing it to others under a non-GPL-compatible license.

Comment: They also offer a commercial license now. (I've updated the link to point to the new site, which has the new licensing options.)

Answer (score 14):

```
<?
# ------- The graph values in the form of associative array
$values=array(
    "Jan" => 110,
    "Feb" => 130,
    "Mar" => 215,
    "Apr" => 81,
    "May" => 310,
    "Jun" => 110,
    "Jul" => 190,
    "Aug" => 175,
    "Sep" => 390,
    "Oct" => 286,
    "Nov" => 150,
    "Dec" => 196
);


$img_width=450;
$img_height=300; 
$margins=20;


# ---- Find the size of graph by substracting the size of borders
$graph_width=$img_width - $margins * 2;
$graph_height=$img_height - $margins * 2; 
$img=imagecreate($img_width,$img_height);


$bar_width=20;
$total_bars=count($values);
$gap= ($graph_width- $total_bars * $bar_width ) / ($total_bars +1);


# -------  Define Colors ----------------
$bar_color=imagecolorallocate($img,0,64,128);
$background_color=imagecolorallocate($img,240,240,255);
$border_color=imagecolorallocate($img,200,200,200);
$line_color=imagecolorallocate($img,220,220,220);

# ------ Create the border around the graph ------

imagefilledrectangle($img,1,1,$img_width-2,$img_height-2,$border_color);
imagefilledrectangle($img,$margins,$margins,$img_width-1-$margins,$img_height-1-$margins,$background_color);


# ------- Max value is required to adjust the scale -------
$max_value=max($values);
$ratio= $graph_height/$max_value;


# -------- Create scale and draw horizontal lines  --------
$horizontal_lines=20;
$horizontal_gap=$graph_height/$horizontal_lines;

for($i=1;$i<=$horizontal_lines;$i++){
    $y=$img_height - $margins - $horizontal_gap * $i ;
    imageline($img,$margins,$y,$img_width-$margins,$y,$line_color);
    $v=intval($horizontal_gap * $i /$ratio);
    imagestring($img,0,5,$y-5,$v,$bar_color);

}


# ----------- Draw the bars here ------
for($i=0;$i< $total_bars; $i++){ 
    # ------ Extract key and value pair from the current pointer position
    list($key,$value)=each($values); 
    $x1= $margins + $gap + $i * ($gap+$bar_width) ;
    $x2= $x1 + $bar_width; 
    $y1=$margins +$graph_height- intval($value * $ratio) ;
    $y2=$img_height-$margins;
    imagestring($img,0,$x1+3,$y1-10,$value,$bar_color);imagestring($img,0,$x1+3,$img_height-15,$key,$bar_color);        
    imagefilledrectangle($img,$x1,$y1,$x2,$y2,$bar_color);
}
header("Content-type:image/png");
imagepng($img);
$_REQUEST['asdfad']=234234;

?>
```

Comment: Please use `<?php ... ?>` instead of `<? ... ?>`.

Comment: Great solution I upvoted but what is $_REQUEST['asdfad']=234234; used for at the end of the script?

Answer (score 12):

Your best bet is to look up php_gd2.  It's a fairly decent image library that comes with PHP (just disabled in php.ini), and not only can you output your finished images in a couple formats, it's got enough functions that you should be able to do up a good graph fairly easily.

EDIT: it might help if I gave you a couple useful links:

http://www.libgd.org/ - You can get the latest `php_gd2` here
https://www.php.net/gd - The `php_gd` manual.

Comment: Kind of reinventing the wheel.. unless you want to build your own framework.

Comment: not sure if it's a useful answer really.  Say I want to smooth a curve, add a legend, position legend text at top or bottom, position major tick marks and minor tick marks like so, add a second, third, fourth Y-axis line, etc.  Seems like a pain to generate your own chart.  This is great for someone who wants to create a charting software, but when it comes to using a charting software, and wants developer speed, this is just too much pain.

Answer (score 11):

You can use [google's chart api](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/types.html) to generate charts.

Comment: Google Chart Api is client side only now. They use to offer a server side download but that is long gone.

Answer (score 6):

There are a number of libraries available for generating graphs.

- [Open Flash Cart](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart-2/) - Flash based
- [GraPHPite](http://graphpite.sourceforge.net/)
- [JS charts](http://www.jscharts.com/) - Javascript based
- [Libchart](http://naku.dohcrew.com/libchart/pages/introduction/)

More are listed above and [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/10/18/charts-and-graphs-modern-solutions/).

Comment: GraPHPite is ordinary and is not an active project.

Answer (score 5):

By far the easiest solution is to just use the Google Chart API
http://code.google.com/apis/chart/

You can make bar graphs, pie charts, use 3D, and it's as easy as building a url with some parameters. See the simple example below.

[image: This Pie Chart is really easy to make]

Answer (score 4):

There are also several graphing libraries available for PHP to make your life simpler. [JPGraph](http://www.aditus.nu/jpgraph/) is a good (non-free) one.

Comment: I have used JPGraph before and the free version of the software is also very good. For the simple problem that needs to be solved I think it will suffice.

Comment: JPGraph is an excellent lib. Many types of graphs and many options. It is free for non commercial project.

Answer (score 1):

Have no idea about gd2, but I have done a similar thing with gd
and it was not that hard.

Go to http://www.php.net/ and search for things like

- ImageCreate
- imageline
- imagestring

It's not as flashy as some of those other solution out there, 
but since you generate a picture it will work in all browsers.
(except lynx... :-) )

/Johan

---

**Update:** I nearly forgot, don't use jpeg for this type of pictures.
The jpeg artefacts will be really annoying, 
png is a better solution.

Comment: As far as I can tell, gd and gd2 seems to be fairly similar, with gd2 just being a later version (with "2" tacked on to the DLL's filename).

Comment: Have no idea about any dll's since I apt-get my software ;-)