# Need a good library for plotting a curve

Tags: php, jquery, graph, curve

I am looking for something like http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/tracking/index.html.
The only problem is that I need y axis to show altitude and x axis to show time of the day. How can I do this; I can use php or jquery for this work, so any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to draw a graph in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645582/how-to-draw-a-graph-in-php)

Comment: Check [JpGraph](http://jpgraph.net/).

Comment: need a way to track the altitude of the curve as the user moves along the curve

Answer (score 2):

have a look at

> highcharts.com

may that helps.

Comment: there was no way of tracking altitude along the curve with highcharts.

Comment: have you checked all the graphs?

Comment: I was working on one, but in the end was not able to solve the problem with that :(

Comment: by the way d3js is also grt source for graphs and curves.

Answer (score 2):

or maybe you find something in this library.

http://d3js.org/

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with Flot plugin by setting:

```
xaxis: {
    mode: "time",
    timeformat: "%Y/%m/%d"
}
```

You can adjust it by other options as well. Take a look at this:
https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#time-series-data

**---- EDIT ----**

Here you go:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZDt7h/7/

```
$(function(){
    var $placeholder = $('#placeholder');
    var start = 1361399340000;   
    var serie = [[start, 1],[start+60E3, 2],[start+120E3, 3],[start+180E3, 2]];

    var myplot = $.plot($placeholder, [serie], {
        xaxis: {
            mode: 'time',
            timeformat: '%H:%M:%S'
        },
        series: {
            'shadowSize': 0,
            'points': {
                'show': true
            },
            'lines': {
                'show': true
            }
        },
        crosshair: { 'mode': 'x' },
        grid: { 'hoverable': true, 'autoHighlight': true }
    });

    $('#update').click(function(){
        serie.push([start+(serie.length)*60E3, Math.floor(Math.random()*10)]);
        myplot.setData([serie]);
        myplot.setupGrid();
        myplot.draw();
    });
});
```

Comment: I can use four points per day based on time and altitude..other than that I need that when the user moves along , the altitude can also be tracked at all times..could u show an example ?